# SparkR code fails if Apache Arrow is enabled

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, sparkr, apache-arrow

I am running gapply function on SparkRDataframe which looks like below

```
 df<-gapply(sp_Stack, function(key,e) {
    
      Sys.setlocale('LC_COLLATE','C')
   
      suppressPackageStartupMessages({ 
      library(Rcpp)
      library(Matrix)
      library(reshape)
      require(parallel)
      require(lubridate)
      library(plyr)
      library(reticulate)
      library(stringr)
      
      library(data.table)
   })
      calcDecsOnly(e,RequestNumber=RequestNumber,
                   ...)
    },cols="udim",schema=schema3)
```

The above code runs without any errors if we set spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkr.enabled = "false" , but if I set spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkr.enabled = "true" the spark Job fails with below error

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.ArrowRRunner$$anon$2.read(ArrowRRunner.scala:154)
```

Environment : Google Cloud Dataproc
Spark version : 3.1.1
Dataproc version : Custom image built on 2.0.9-debian10

Any help here is appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try non-custom image and other image versions?

Comment: Yes I tried with the latest image dataproc-version 2.0.12-debian10  I tried with both arrow-4.0.1 and arrow-3.0.0

Comment: Did you install Arrow by yourself?

Comment: Yes , I did it as part of initialisation script of custom Dataproc image. command used /opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/conda install r-arrow==3.0.0

Comment: Could you try this instruction? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sparkr.html#apache-arrow-in-sparkr

Comment: I did try this , in fact I am using both installation instruction in my image creation /opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/conda install r-arrow==3.0.0 as well as the one mentioned in the doc above. If I only use Rscript -e 'install.packages("arrow", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/") arrow does not get installed correctly in Dataproc executors

Comment: Did you guys try increasing the memory for non-JVM processes on the executors? This looks like an error on the JVM executor read side where the streaming arrow data is halting early. This could be due to a crash of the R sidecar process due to something as trivial as OOM. I'd recommend attempting to bump the value of spark.executor.memoryOverhead which defaults to 10% of spark.executor.memory. Do note that Dataproc defaults spark.executor.memory based on VM size for executor bin packing, if you bump memoryOverhead you may want an equal decrease in memory to ensure good resource utilization.

Comment: Hey , I had tried with increased overhead memory as R process gets it memory from overhead, Did not help though. Our R process is CPU intensive , I also think CPU may be a bottleneck here, however I did not find a way to give dedicated CPU to Backend (tried numbackendthreads)